# Google Map API: Display of alternative bus routes possible?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bus

So far I am only able to show a only single bus route when using Google Maps API v3. However on google websites, one active route and other 2-3 grayed out ones are shown.

1. Is there an option in the API v3 to enable alternative bus routes or do I have to custom code that feature?

[image]

2. How do you select directions for specific time and date in future like on google maps?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. you'll need to set the `provideRouteAlternatives`-option of the `DirectionsRequest` to `true`, then you may(when available) get alternative routes.

   To draw the multiple routes you must create separate `DirectionsRenderer`-instances for each route and set the index of the desired route as `routeIndex`-property of the `DirectionsRenderer`
2. the time(departure/arrival) may be specified via the [`transitOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#TransitOptions) of the `DirectionsRequest`